# Can a DEFINER be a role instead of a user?

Tags: mysql, security, mariadb

In MSSQL I'm used to using roles for security and permissions but in MySQL/MariaDB it seems that users are a staple that you can't really get around. One specific case I'm wondering about is a DEFINER on a view or stored procedure. I essentially can't script that object without knowing what user it should run as ahead of time, in my case. Is there a way to define it with a specific role instead of a user?

Comment: From version 8.0.0 of MySQL [(Using Roles)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/roles.html) and 10.0.5 of MariaDB [(Roles)](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/roles/), it's possible to use roles, so, probably, you can achieve what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
CREATE DEFINER=`your role` PROCEDURE / FUNCTION ()
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER -- that's the default
begin
    ....
end
```

'Your role' must have execute permission for the procedure und all the privileges needed inside the procedure.